# NodeJS - Error Building Server

Tags: node.js

If I use `Node.js command prompt` and make:

```
cd "Directory"
node app.js
```

The server will run just fine, and works fine to.
But, if I open the cmd.exe and make:

```
cd "Directory"
node app.js
```

I will get this error. Why? The error is on the opening of my C\C++ addon.

[image]

Edit: Invocation of addon

```
var addon = require('./build/Release/addon.node');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aperently this is not loading the `nodevars.bat` by default. 
If I make:

```
cd "nodevars.bat directory"
nodevars.bat
cd "app.js directory"
node app.js
```

Will be work. Now the new doubt is: how I can add this to cmd.exe by default? To have no need of doing the 1st and 2nd step again?